# error: 'any object' not convertible to [pf object]

Tags: ios, swift

I am having two errors that I am getting in this function. I am unsure how to resolve if anyone has any suggestions please let me know :)

```
func loaddData() {
    timelineData.removeAllObjects()

    var findTimelineData:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Tweets")

    findTimelineData.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!)->Void in

        if !error{
            for object:[PFObject]! in objects{
                self.timelineData.addObject(object)
            }

            let array:NSArray = self.timelineData.reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects
            self.timelineData
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the errors? You haven't said where they are happening or what they are.

Comment: My mistake. the error is happening on the line for object:[PFObject]! in objects{

Comment: use `for object in objects as [PHFObject]{}`

Comment: eror is 'AnyObject is not convertible to [anyObject]

Comment: @JackWu where should I try that at? and is that all I would change?

Comment: @Jorden15 in place of the error line of course! Simply cast the array `objects` to type `[PFObject]`. When you iterate over it, you would get a `PHFObject` every time.

Answer (score 2):

```
for object:[PFObject]! in objects {
    self.timelineData.addObject(object)
}
```

should be change to:

```
for object in objects as [PFObject] {
    self.timelineData.addObject(object)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you are declaring `objects` as an array of objects of type `AnyObject`.
Then, when you try to iterate the items in the array you say that each item is an array of objects of type `AnyObject`. This is wrong because at first you declared it differently.

To fix it, change:

```
for object:[PFObject]! in objects {
    self.timelineData.addObject(object)
}
```

To:

```
for object:AnyObject in objects {
    self.timelineData.addObject(object as PFObject)
}
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error when I tried this. :/